# Product of two multivariate Gaussian vectors

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I am working on some project, and i am currently trying to find if there exists an **analytical** formula for the product of two Gaussian **vectors** $\ x$ and $\ y$, where $\ y|y_h\equiv N(y_H, \sigma_1^{2})$ and $x|y\equiv N(Ay, \sigma_2^{2})$ where $A$ is a matrix with size $16\times 24$. I bumped into this whole article (http://www.tina-vision.net/docs/memos/2003-003.pdf), which has the formula that I need, but I am not sure how do they come up with co-variance matrix $V$ in the formula;p.

**Question:** Could someone kindly help explain to me how to apply that formula for the specific case of $p(x|y)\ p(y|y_h)$, assume each follows normal distribution but they are **vectors**, not **random variables**?

Comment: First I assume you have not mixed up the terminology, then you need to clarify what product of vectors are you referring to. Please clarify the notation and the dimensions of the random vectors as well. Also, in the given link the whole document is talking about the product of two normal pdf, not the product of two normal random variables. At the end of the article the author also warned this - it is not the pdf of the product of normal. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalProductDistribution.html

Comment: @BGM: Thank you for your comment. I was talking about the inner product of two pdfs. About your question: $y_H$ and $y$ both have the dimensions $24\times 1$. Which notation do you want me to clarify though? 
I think my modeling was meaningless by assuming a variance of the normal distribution to be a co-variance matrix, especially when the components seem to be well-justified to be independent;p